# How to handle missing values in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

```
A = ds.iloc[:,0:4].values
B = ds.iloc[:,-1].values

imp = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)
imp = impsqft.fit(A[:,3])
A[:,3] = imp.transform(A[:,3])
```

I want to replace 4th column with mean of that column for null values but it gives me below error:

```
array=[  1.   2.  nan   4.   1.   2.   4.  nan   2.   3.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Formatted Correction to get good answers

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The Imputer class needs a matrix as an input for the `fit` method.

You can either try to format it with the `reshape` method like the error message says

```
mp = impsqft.fit(A[:,3].reshape(-1, 1))
```

or the easiest is to pass a matrix and not a list.

```
       A = ds.iloc[:,0:4]
```

Comment: then how to take it into the matrix form

Comment: @chetansharma like I wrote: instead of calling `.values` on `ds.iloc[:, 0:4]`, try without the `.values` at the end. `A = ds.iloc[:,0:4]`, and try to adapt the rest of your code.